# How to manually connect model fields validator to a form field

Tags: django

I believe that modelform know how to use model field validators. I'm creating a dynamic form and I need to replicate this behavior so i don't violate DRY. Where do I connect these two?

Comment: If you provide the relevant portion of your code this will be easier to answer.

Comment: I'll try and frame up a simple example

Answer (score 2):

**django/forms/forms.py**

`is_valid` form method is calling form `full_clean` method from form `_get_errors` here (`self.errors=property(_get_errors)`):

```
return self.is_bound and not bool(self.errors)
```

`full_clean` calls this sequence of functions:

```
self._clean_fields()
self._clean_form()
self._post_clean()
```

And here the function you are looking for i think:

```
def _post_clean(self):
    """
    An internal hook for performing additional cleaning after form cleaning
    is complete. Used for model validation in model forms.
    """
    pass
```

**django/forms/models.py**

```
def _post_clean(self):
    opts = self._meta
    # Update the model instance with self.cleaned_data.
    self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)

    exclude = self._get_validation_exclusions()

    # Foreign Keys being used to represent inline relationships
    # are excluded from basic field value validation. This is for two
    # reasons: firstly, the value may not be supplied (#12507; the
    # case of providing new values to the admin); secondly the
    # object being referred to may not yet fully exist (#12749).
    # However, these fields *must* be included in uniqueness checks,
    # so this can't be part of _get_validation_exclusions().
    for f_name, field in self.fields.items():
        if isinstance(field, InlineForeignKeyField):
            exclude.append(f_name)

    # Clean the model instance's fields.
    try: 
        self.instance.clean_fields(exclude=exclude)
    except ValidationError, e:
        self._update_errors(e.message_dict)

    # Call the model instance's clean method.
    try: 
        self.instance.clean()
    except ValidationError, e:
        self._update_errors({NON_FIELD_ERRORS: e.messages})

    # Validate uniqueness if needed.
    if self._validate_unique:
        self.validate_unique()
```

So, model form validation differs from simple form validation by performing additional calls to model `instance._clean_fields(exclude=exclude)` (some fields excluded from validation) and `instance.clean()`.